# MongoDB Database, equivalent for SELECT column1, column2 FROM tbl

Tags: select, mongodb, rows

From my MongoDB I want the equivalent for

```
  SELECT column1, column2
  FROM tbl
```

With this code I get all the 'rows' but also all the 'columns'

```
  DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("names");
  DBCursor cursor = collection.find();
```

I for example would like **all** the 'rows' but **only** the 'columns':  id, name, age

How would I do this?

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> db.collection.find({}, {_id: 1, name: 1, age: 1})

The first argument to find (the predicate) is your selection criteria, e.g.

> db.collection.find({age: {$gte: 21}})

The second limits the fields you retrieve, so for the names over everyone 21 or older:

> db.collection.find({age: {$gte: 21}}, {name: 1})

The field selector always pulls back _id unless you specifically turn it off:

> db.collection.find({}, {_id: 0})

However, Mongo will not check for field existence by default. If you want to select certain fields, and match only results that have those fields, you will want to use:

> db.collection.find({ age: { $exists: true } })

The MongoDB website has a more detailed description of the .find() function!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks!, I fixed it with the code below.

```
    BasicDBObject select = new BasicDBObject();
    select.put("id", 1);
    select.put("name", 1);
    select.put("age", 1);
    collection.find(new BasicDBObject(), select);
```

Above code gives me all the records, with only the column names as above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want select one or multiple columns like SQL query. for example
if your SQL query like this

```
select name, content from knowledgebase where applicationId='2955f3e174dce55190a87ed0e133adwdeb92';
```

MongoDB query:

```
db.knowledgebase.find({ "applicationId": "2955f3e174dce55190a87ed0e133adwdeb92"}, { "name": 1,    "content": 1});
```