# What is the equivalent of SELECT in mongodb?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to query a collection in MongoDB where I just want the data of a particular user to be returned. I'm sure `SELECT` is the parameter used to do this in MySQL but do mongo has the same feature?

I just want the results from `username: meme_africa` to be returned.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a90bfeec1f61a1fcc51bfa0"
    },
    "username": "meme_africa",
    "imgs": "zuma.jpeg",
    "uploadDate": {
        "$date": "2018-02-24T01:29:18.639Z"
    },
    "tags": [],
    "__v": 0
}
```

How can I do this in mongo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB Database, equivalent for SELECT column1, column2 FROM tbl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206035/mongodb-database-equivalent-for-select-column1-column2-from-tbl)

Comment: Your answer works.Thanks, @ReyanChougle.